# How do I get this video player to work with html5 ogv and mp4 on the web?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video, vorbis

I am trying out some video player i found on the web that uses CSS3 HTML5 JQUERY etc... http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/#sec1

I am trying to add it to an existing site but it just wont work in firefox when I upload it to the web.  I thought it was due to the filesize of the mp4/ogv files being too large but none of the controls come up so something must be interfering with the javascript library.

I haven't touched the js and css files that were given in the source code at the bottom of the tutorial. Only the HTML index page. which you can see below by clicking that link and checking the source

[`http://themeditationfactory.com/SIDC/Videos`](http://themeditationfactory.com/SIDC/Videos/)

Comment: The original video in dev.opera.com doesn't work in Firefox either

Comment: Firefox only has MP4 if you're on Windows and OGG is what you're looking for (not OGV.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to your server configuration, to the way your server is serving the ogv files. You should check the section about Mine Types on Dive Into HTML5. 
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

I'm the author of the article, and I've written a more recent **[article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/more-accessible-html5-video-player/)**, about the same video player.

Also, the player has evolved a lot, it's now called Acorn Media Player, is accessible, has more themes, support for the audio element and many others.

You can find the repo on [Github](http://www.github.com/ghinda/acornmediaplayer).
You'll also find better documentation there.

After you make sure your server configuration is correct, my suggestion is that you use the new version of the plugin, not the one from the first article.